# How can I add values in different line strings?

Tags: javascript

I have some data which contains multiple lines as shown below. I need to add up the values that are in each string.

Original String:

```
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
```

Value calculation I needed:

1. I should be able to read each line and add up '10M' placement value eventually
2. I should be able skip any line that starts with 'nfs','udev'
3. 3-4, 5-6, 7-8 lines are supposed to be in the same line but due to the string length 4, 6, 8 lines went to new line.

I tried the below code but I am just able to capture the values that are in single line ex.1st line and last line since everything is in same line.

```
let lines = '/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
let gb = 0;
let mb = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var disk = lines[i];
    if (!disk.startsWith('udev') && !disk.startsWith('nfs')){
            var diskSpace = disk.split(/\s+/).slice(1,2).toString();

            if(diskSpace.indexOf('G')> -1){
                gb = gb + parseInt(diskSpace);

            }if(diskSpace.indexOf('M')> -1){
                mb = mb + parseInt(diskSpace) / 1024;

            }
        }
    }
    console.log(gb  + mb);
```

Answer would be: 30

Comment: To be clear, does `lines` have the extra lines breaks that you mention in point 3, or not? (It would be helpful, to just provide the *exact* string value in your code as a string literal, including all linebreaks. That way there is no ambiguity)

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the reply. I updated the 3rd point. Whole string it self comes with broken lines. I have to code that way to support.

Answer (score 3):

I would chain each step of the process, using array methods (`filter`, `map`, `reduce`), so you get a functional approach:

```js
let lines = `/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot`;

let sum = 
    // split into lines, keeping broken parts together
    lines.split(/\n(?=\S)/)
    // exclude lines with certain prefixes
    .filter(line => !line.startsWith("nfs/") && !line.startsWith("udev/"))
    // extract the numbers and their unit of measure
    .map(line => line.match(/\s\d+[MG]/))
    // convert to numbers in Megabytes
    .map(([str]) => parseInt(str) * (str.endsWith("G") ? 1024 : 1))
    // sum up
    .reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

If you don't have ES6 support for arrow syntax, then you can fall back to older syntax:

```js
var lines = "/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot\n" +
    "udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home\n" +
    "/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv\n" + 
    "                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home\n" + 
    "nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv\n" + 
    "                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home\n" + 
    "udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv\n" + 
    "                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home\n" + 
    "/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot";

var sum = 
    // split into lines, keeping broken parts together
    lines.split(/\n(?=\S)/)
    // exclude lines with certain prefixes
    .filter(function (line) {
         return line.indexOf("nfs/") !== 0 && line.indexOf("udev/") !== 0;
    })
    // extract the numbers and their unit of measure
    .map(function (line) {
         return line.match(/\s\d+[MG]/);
    })
    // convert to numbers in Megabytes
    .map(function (arr) {
         return parseInt(arr[0]) * (arr[0].slice(-1) === "G" ? 1024 : 1);
    })
    // sum up
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
         return a+b;
    }, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting this warning ''arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option). Is there any alternative?

Comment: @evan: Use something like Babel to precompile it for you, or simply replace all `(foo) => bar` with `function(foo) {return bar;}`  (There's a little added complexity for the `([str]) => parseInt...` line, but it's not complex.)

Comment: I added the same solution in an older JS syntax (ES5).

Comment: @TylerRoper, the original question was confusing (the use of `lines.length` in the code), but I have indeed now adapted it to work on a single text string.

Answer (score 1):

A few things, first due to the random spacing. I simply removed that in order to create consistent lines. I added a reusable function for REPLACEALL if you want to reuse it in the future. Then I simply split `\n`. Also for your adding, I had to remove the `G` and the `M` before adding the values.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    var str = this;
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), replace);
};

let lines = `/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot`;

lines = lines.replaceAll("\n                      ","  ").split("\n");

var gb = 0;mb = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var disk = lines[i];
    if (!disk.startsWith('udev') && !disk.startsWith('nfs')){
            var diskSpace = disk.split(/\s+/).slice(1,2).toString();

            if(diskSpace.indexOf('G')> -1){
                diskSpace = diskSpace.replace("G","");
                gb = gb + parseInt(diskSpace);

            }if(diskSpace.indexOf('M')> -1){
                diskSpace = diskSpace.replace("M","");
                mb = mb + parseInt(diskSpace) / 1024;

            }
        }
    }
    console.log(gb,mb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split this string into lines by using `split(\n)`, join the wrapped lines, then filter out all the lines that starts with `nfs` or `udev`.

When you have only the relevant lines, use `reduce` to accumulate the values.

```js
const str = `/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot`;

const joinBreakedLines = function(result, currentLine) {
  if (currentLine.startsWith('   ')) {
    result[result.length - 1] += '  ' + currentLine.trim();
  } else {
    result.push(currentLine);
  }
  return result;
};

const sum = str
  .split('\n')
  .reduce(joinBreakedLines, [])
  .filter(function(line) {
    return !(line.startsWith('udev') || line.startsWith('nfs'));
  })
  .map(function(line) {
    return line.split('  ');
  })
  .reduce(function(result, line) {
    const value = line[1].slice(0, -1);
    return result + parseInt(value, 10);
  }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @felixmosh I am getting this warning ''arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option). Is there any alternative?

Comment: Sure, just change this to `function()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the lines into an array and use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum them. The benefit to this approach is that it only requires you to loop through the array once to produce the sum.

Details are included as comments in the code.

```js
let lines = `/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot`;

var result = lines
  .split(/(?=\/dev\/|udev|nfs)/g)               //Split lines into array
  .reduce(function(sum, line) {
    if (!line.startsWith("/dev/")) return sum;  //Ignore lines that don't start with "/dev/"

    var diskspace = line.match(/\S+/g)[1];      //Split on spaces, get second value
    return diskspace.endsWith("G") ?            
      sum + parseInt(diskspace) * 1024 :        //gb - multiply by 1024
      sum + parseInt(diskspace);                //mb - leave as-is
  }, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce, split, indexOf

1. Replace new lines ('\n') with space and split by space(' ') and remove empty values by filter(Boolean) using below code

   **str.replace(/\n|\r/g, " ").split(' ').filter(Boolean)**
2. Check path by splitting string with '/' and count > 1 and checking whether it starts with 'udev' or 'nfs'

   **v.split('/').length > 1 && !v.startsWith('nfs') &&  !v.startsWith('udev')**
3. If Step 2 is valid, then add next value to accumulator value - acc by checking whether next value is available or not , defined and number

`if(i+1){
           if(self[i+1] && !isNaN(parseInt(self[i+1])*1)){
              acc =acc + parseInt(self[i+1])

           }
         }`

Code sample -

```js
var str = `/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv 976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-homelv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
nfs/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      10M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
udev/mapper/sysvg-optlv
                      976M  2.3M  923M   1% /home
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  10M  141M  311M  32% /boot
`

console.log(str.replace(/\n|\r/g, " ").split(' ').filter(Boolean).reduce((acc, v, i, self) => {
   if(v.split('/').length > 1 && !v.startsWith('nfs') &&  !v.startsWith('udev')){    
     if(i+1){
       if(self[i+1] && !isNaN(parseInt(self[i+1])*1)){
          acc =acc + parseInt(self[i+1])         
       }
     }
   }
   return acc
}, 0))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BgzLvQ?editors=1010